# Storing Base64 instead of UUID in Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

Can I store it in a string field. Basically, I will generate a unique id using uuid function and then convert it to base64 that looks like in google then store that in the database.

I'm planning to use cassandra in the future so I'm not sure if there's a performance hit if I'll use string as primary key there.

I just want to know what's the best practice for this.

Thank you.